# Get the translation and rotation components of a quaternion

Tags: rotations, quaternions

Given a quaternion obtained by compositions of rotations and translations, is it safe to take the $3\times 3$ upper left matrix as the "full rotation" and the last column of the matrix as the "full translation" ?

Using block-matrices, I have :
$$
\left[
\begin{matrix}
R & t\\
0 & 1
\end{matrix}
\right]
=
\left[
\begin{matrix}
1 & t\\
0 & 1
\end{matrix}
\right]
\times
\left[
\begin{matrix}
R & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$
where $R$ would be the rotation and $t$ the translation.

Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that what you are describing are not quaternions, they are homogeneous transformations.  A quaternion would be used to perform the same function as your $R$, however, you would not store it (or use it) as a matrix.  Additionally, quaternions do not encode translations, only rotations.

To answer your question, yes you can decompose a homogeneous transformation into its constituent rotation and translation parts and the decomposition that you show above is correct.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was quite convinced that the $4\times 4$ matrix I show is a "quaternion",  welI I was mistaken.